# How many context-classloaders have an EAR?

Tags: java, classloader, ear

I have an EAR project, and I load resources using `getContextClassLoader.getResource`. But when my WAR module and EJB (.jar) module have resources with same name (but different content), I always get resources from EJB, not from web module (resources with same name  from EJB overrides resources from .WAR).

Does this thing related with *context classloader*?

**UPD**: 
Project structure:

```
 -EAR
     -- WEBAPP.WAR
                  ---classes
                             ----my.properties

     -- EJB.JAR
                  ---classes
                            ---- my.properties
```

In `webapp.war` and in `ejb.jar` I have same file (`my.properties`).

But when I use

`Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("My.properties")`

from `webapp.war` I always get `My.properties` from `EJB.JAR`.

Comment: which Application server are you using?

Comment: could you please add the project structure? coz otherwise it is difficult to comment exact problem. And give a sample for what you are trying to load using `getContextClassLoader.getResouce()`

Comment: @NarendraPathai I updated question, please review it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to change the the classpath or dependency of the ear to **WEBAPP.WAR** followed by **EJB.JAR**.

As it looks like when you are using the Context Class Loader which uses the ClassLoader for EAR and tries to look for the resource `My.properties` using its Classpath and finds dependency first in EJB.jar and so uses its file.

So you will have to change the order to WEBAPP.war and then EJB.jar

Comment: If there is a MANIFEST.MF file in META-INF directory of EAR, update it to include `Class-Path: webapp.war ejb.jar `. Create a MANIFEST.MF file in a META-INF directory if not present already.